# Ignite/GridGain putAllIfAbsent

Tags: ignite, gridgain

I am use GridGain as my persistence database. I have following requirements.

1. Insert multiple records if key already not exists
2. Put multiple records if key exists or not.

For 1, I saw `cache.putIfAbsent(key, value)` method to insert single record if not exists. But I didn't find `cache.putAllIfAbsent(Map<key, value>)` like method. I can you loop to insert multiple records one by one. Is it given performance issue?

For 2, I think I can use `cache.putAll(Map<key, value>)` method. If it proper way?

I run server in Google cloud Kubernetes engine as thick clients.

Answer (score 3):

- `putAll` always overwrites existing records
- `putIfAbsent` in a loop will be slower than `putAll`. Measure your specific use case to see by how much

If there is no requirement for ordering and atomicity, [DataStreamer](https://www.gridgain.com/docs/latest/developers-guide/data-streaming) is a good choice. When `allowOverwrite` flag is false (default), you get `putIfAbsent` behavior, and good performance.

```
try (IgniteDataStreamer<Integer, String> stmr = ignite.dataStreamer("myCache")) {    
    stmr.allowOverwrite(false); // Don't overwrite existing data

    Map<Integer, String> entries = getMydata()
    stmr.addData(entries);
}
```